# Distance between two coordinates

Tags: distance, coordinates

I have two coordinates.

```
Lat:53.307718   Long:-6.230189

Lat:53.307708   Long:-6.229988
```

.

I then use the distance formula

```
distance = SQRT((Y2-Y1)*(Y2-Y1) +(X2-X1)*(X2-X1))
```

.

I put it points in.

```
distance = SQRT((53.307708-53.307718)*(53.307708-53.307718) +(-6.229988--6.230189)*(-6.229988--6.230189))
```

and it get a value of 0.000201

What is the factor to convert that point to convert to meters?

I but the two points into this website http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html and found the distance to be 12.92 meters. But when i do it then for the next point the factor isnt the same.

Comment: This q/a may help too, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76276/how-can-i-calculate-the-distances-between-my-points-in-sequence-automatically

Comment: You didn't multiply it by circumference distance

Answer (score 1):

Because the Earth is not a perfect sphere the actual distance represented by a degree ( or a fraction of a degree ) will vary based on the latitude.

This can be seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees):
[image]

So you will be able to get the difference in decimal degree using the distance formula but to convert them you will need to use the corresponding factor.