# How to calculate the distance between points (pointlayer)

Tags: qgis, distance

I am totally new to QGIS and I have a List of Trackpoints which I loaded in QGIS as a CSV (with the GEOCSV plugin to be able to edit the layer).So I have a Layer with ~1000 Points now.

I like to add a column "distance" in the table of attributes with the distance from the previous point. The Distance should be calculated using latitide and longitude.

Comment: Here is an answer for the use in a spreadsheet program like excel or libreoffice if this is an option. https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/76282/69528

Answer (score 2):

**QGIS 3.0**

If you are working on a `Points` layer which is on *UTM zone 54N (EPSG:32654)*, then try:

```
distance(transform(geometry(get_feature_by_id('Points', $id+1)),'EPSG:4326','EPSG:32654'), 
         transform(geometry(get_feature_by_id('Points',   $id)),'EPSG:4326','EPSG:32654'))
```

Please edit `'Points'` (layer name) and `'EPSG:32654'` (your working CRS) as required.