# How to calculate difference in time and distance between consecutive rows in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a attribute table that looks like this. I want to calculate the difference in time and distance between consecutive rows.

```
fid  car_id   lng       lat         time
1    57       4.932413  52.372022   2018-03-04 06:21:12
2    57       4.932533  52.372323   2018-03-04 06:21:41
3    57       4.932553  52.372994   2018-03-04 06:22:22
4    57       4.932663  52.372312   2018-03-04 06:23:15
5    57       4.932333  52.372582   2018-03-04 06:24:17
6    57       4.932213  52.372693   2018-03-04 06:24:53
7    26       4.932223  52.372343   2018-03-04 06:25:11
8    26       4.932413  52.372372   2018-03-04 06:25:48
9    26       4.932103  52.372952   2018-03-04 06:26:16
10   26       4.932223  52.372912   2018-03-04 06:26:30
```

Eventually I would like to have something like this with distance difference in meters and difference in time in seconds. Any advice on how to do this in QGIS?

```
fid  car_id   lng       lat         time                   distance_diff    time_diff
1    57       4.932413  52.372022   2018-03-04 06:21:12    0                0
2    57       4.932533  52.372323   2018-03-04 06:21:41    47               20
3    57       4.932553  52.372994   2018-03-04 06:22:22    29               41
4    57       4.932663  52.372312   2018-03-04 06:23:15    58               53
5    57       4.932333  52.372582   2018-03-04 06:24:17    46               62
6    57       4.932213  52.372693   2018-03-04 06:24:53    56               36
7    26       4.932223  52.372343   2018-03-04 06:25:11    38               18
8    26       4.932413  52.372372   2018-03-04 06:25:48    60               37
9    26       4.932103  52.372952   2018-03-04 06:26:16    21               28
10   26       4.932223  52.372912   2018-03-04 06:26:30    31               14
```

Answer (score 2):

(1) To calculate the `time_diff` field, try this expression:

```
second(age(attribute($currentfeature, 'time'), 
           attribute(get_feature_by_id('your_layername',$id-1), 'time')))
```

(Please change the `'your_layername'` part to your actual layername).

[image]

If you are unhappy with `NULL` returned for the first row ('fid' = 1), wrap it in a conditional statement, like:

```
CASE WHEN fid=1 THEN 0
ELSE
second(age(attribute($currentfeature, 'time'), 
           attribute(get_feature_by_id('your_layername',$id-1), 'time')))
END
```

(2) To calculate the `distance_diff`, you may find another post [How to calculate the distance between points (pointlayer)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/246133/84455) useful. However, you will need to find a best CRS for your area. As you are working in relatively high latitude, UTM may not give you an accurate distance.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code. Unfortunately the code generates a column with only NULL values. I did change 'your_layername' to my actual layername.. Any idea what the problem might me?

Comment: I think it had something to do with the fid column. I manually added a new $id column and it works now. Thanks!

Comment: Export layer to MS Excel  and calculate difference. Then link layer with excel table with ID field, and import difference in time.

Comment: So I got this perfectly working when using the field calculator outside the graphic modeler. However, when I want to calculate the time difference with the field calculator in a graphical model, it does not work.. It only generates NULL values. Any ideas what the problem is?