# Loop an operation in all features

Tags: pyqgis, features, loop, time

I have a layer that has date and time information and I need the difference between this information in seconds, I managed to get close to this but I needed to loop for the difference between the features.
I used something like:

```py
campotempo = pr.fieldNameIndex('Data/Hora GPS')
tempo1= feature1.attributes()[campotempo]
tempo2 = feature2.attributes()[campotempo]
tempo1form = datetime.datetime.strptime(tempo1, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
tempo2form = datetime.datetime.strptime(tempo2, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
datarange = ((tempo1form - tempo2form).seconds)
with edit(vl):
  for f in vl.getFeatures():
    f['Tempo(s)'] = datarange
    vl.updateFeature(f)
```

But it did not work

[image]

How can I use PyQGIS to make the difference between the time of each feature?

Comment: Yea, but I dont know how to do this in pyqgis, Just in fieldcalculator

Comment: Is your field 'Tempo(s)' formatted as a decimal or a datetime?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an expression like [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/352940/how-to-calculate-difference-in-time-and-distance-between-consecutive-rows-in-qgi), which you can execute using python like [this](https://opensourceoptions.com/pyqgis-calculate-geometry-and-field-values-with-the-qgis-python-api/).

If you dont want to use expression you can:

```
import datetime
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("pointswithtime")[0]
timefield = "gpstime"

#Add the tempo field
pr = layer.dataProvider()
fieldname = "tempo"
pr.addAttributes([QgsField(fieldname, QVariant.Int)])
layer.updateFields()
ix = layer.fields().indexFromName(fieldname)
    
#List all features and sort by timestamp. You might want to sort by something else?
features = [[f.id(), datetime.datetime.strptime(f[timefield], "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")] for f in layer.getFeatures()]
features.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])

ids = [x[0] for x in features] #Extract the ids
timestamps = [x[1] for x in features] #And timestamps

#Calculate diff between row2-row1, row3-row2, ... and insert a starting None/NULL value
deltas = [None]+[(b-a).seconds for a,b in zip(timestamps, timestamps[1:])]

attributemap = {id : {ix: d} for id, d in zip(ids, deltas)} #A dict of {feature id : {fieldindex to update: value}, ..
pr.changeAttributeValues(attributemap) #Update the values
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, it works! Thank you very much, but now I have another problem, the layer with time and the calculation of the time difference that has IDs is filtered, that is, the layer does not start at ID 1, and I need to place the field with the calculated times in another layer that starts with ID 1, I managed to do this but when transferring the field, it starts at the ID of the filtered layer. Remembering that the filtered layer has X features, the layer where I want to place the time delta has X -1 features (all data will be used, considering that the time delta 1 is NULL)

Answer (score 0):

Check your field data type.  If it is decimal you will have to convert your datarange variable to a float.  Your code should work.  I tested with putting a decimal in *datarange*.  Also getting the difference between 2 datetimes should result in a datetime.timedelta.

```
    #Lists Fields in current layer
from datetime import timedelta
current_fields = []
layer = iface.activeLayer()
lfields = layer.fields()
for fld in lfields:
    fname = fld.name()
    current_fields.append(fname)
print(current_fields)
#datarange = timedelta(seconds = 4.5)
datarange = 4.5
with edit(layer):
  for f in layer.getFeatures():
    f['Tempo(s)'] = datarange
    f["Name"] = "hello"
    layer.updateFeature(f)
```