# How to convert distance into latitude + longitude

Tags: gps, distance, geolocation

I have start point (latitude) I know direction, lets say strictly north, and I want to calculate latitude which is 100 meters above the start point.

The same for longitude.

I believe there should be a simple way to do that, but I couldn't find any relevant to this, only how to calculate distance knowing start and end points.

Comment: 1/ How far are the "jump" distances? Only few hundreds of meters or 5000km? 2/ What is your area of interest (min/max latitude)?

Comment: single jump from one point to another would be really tiny, I would say even tens of meters, area is not determined

Comment: There is a quite complicated formula, it is called Clarke's method or something like that. If I find it in my materials, I'll post it here.

Comment: If you want to do this correctly, the Lengthy formula is given on this page: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html Go to the section titled: `Destination point given distance and bearing from start point`

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple and accurate way to do it because ellipsoid. conversion to meters varies depending latitude.

See : [Understanding terms in Length of Degree formula?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75528/length-of-a-degree-where-do-the-terms-in-this-formula-come-from/75535#75535)

one way to make it very simple (but not very accurate) is use table from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees. use 0.001 degrees and trigonometry to solve points

Comment: thank you, actually I don't need good precision and the moment, so probably I can use data from table