# Distance between two latitudes and two longitudes

Tags: latitude-longitude

I would like to know what is the distance in km between two longitudes and two latitudes.

For example, at the same latitude, what is the distance, in km, between longitude x and longitude x+1 (where x is the longitude in decimal).

Same question for latitude: at the same longitude what is the distance, in km, between latitude x and latitude x+1 ? (where x is the latitude in decimal)

Edit to avoid confusion:

I do not want to calculate the distance between two points with latitude and longitude, I want to know how many kilometers is a difference of 1 for two longitudes at the same latitude and two latitudes at the same longitudes.

For example, distance between longitude 43.0 and 44.0 is XXX km.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18883601/function-to-calculate-distance-between-two-coordinates

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding terms in Length of Degree formula?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75528/understanding-terms-in-length-of-degree-formula)

Comment: As a simpler answer, without corrections for the earth not being quite spherical, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically answered your question already.

If you want to get the distance between two latitude values just set the longitude to the same value and calculate the distance between the points and vice versa.

Comment: Ok; thanks. I was hopping that there were an easier way. Thanks.