# Geocentric Coordinate Transformations

Tags: coordinate-system

I have a geocentric coordinate for the position of an object; I am trying to write a function where by an objects position changes with respect to time - moves across the surface at a constant velocity. p(x,y,t) is the position of the object at time t, and at each time step dt is updated by a constant velocity function v(x, y).

I will try my best to explain how I understand the problem, please correct me if I am wrong.

The transformations cannot be applied directly to the geocentric coordinates, since v(x, y) is describing motion on a flat plane. This origin of this flat plane is located at the geocentric coordinates G(X,Y,Z) and is oriented such that the vector G(0, 0, 0)->G(X, Y, Z) is orthogonal to p(x,,) and p(,y,).

I think the problem can be boiled down to, *given a flat space translation (dx,dy) what is the new geocentric coordinate*?

Comment: Because "move" is so non-specific, there can be no possibility of a "canonical" answer. Please edit your question to provide more context so people can identify appropriate and useful answers.

Comment: The intent of your question is now clear, but the meanings of p(x,,) and p(,y,) are not, nor is it apparent what "surface" you are talking about.  In general, motion at a location is described by *two* coordinate systems: one to specify the position (a "global" system) and another in which displacements are given--the "local frame."  These distinctions become apparent during discussions of specific problems, such as at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30448.  Could you provide some information about the "surface" and the meanings of "p(x,,)" and "p(,y,)"?

Comment: The link you posted is what I am after - please close this question as duplicate :)